# Returning multiple array items in a loop swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, for-loop, swift5

I need help. I am trying to bring back separate two array items so that I can apply separate formatting to each i.e. a title and notes. Hence, I cannot bring back one single array.

```swift
let pageTitle: [String] = runs.map({ $0.title })
let pageContent: [String] = runs.map({ $0.notes! })

for text in pagesTitle {
    let vc = TextViewController(with: text, text2: nil)
    myControllers.append(vc)
}
            
for text2 in pagesContent {
    let vc = TextViewController(with: nil, text2: text2)
    myControllers.append(vc)
}
```

I have also tried:

```swift
for text in pageTitle, pageContent {
    let vc = TextViewController(with: text, text2)
    myControllers.append(vc)
}
```

And

```swift
for text in pageTitle {
    for text2 in pageContent {
        let vc = TextViewController(with: text, text2)
        myControllers.append(vc)
    }
}
```

The text and text2 are needed for my init:

```swift
init(with text: String, text2: String) {
    self.myText = text
    self.myText2 = text2
    myTextView.text = self.myText
    myTextView2.text = self.myText2
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let myControllers = runs.map {  TextViewController(with:$0.title, text2:$0.notes!) }
```

OR

```
let myControllers = zip(pageTitle,pageContent).map {  TextViewController(with:$0, text2:$1)  }
```

Comment: Hi @Sh_Khan What would I put in the for loop? your suggestion doesn't work as I need a for loop to generate the required number of VCs.

Comment: I do not understand, I thought I needed a for loop to generate the required numbers of VCs?

Comment: `let myControllers =` is what you need in answer

Comment: When I remove the for loop and just put in the above, I no longer get any view controller generated?

Comment: I believe I need the for loop to generate the number of vcs else how will swift know how many vis to generate? @sh_khan

Comment: @Jones Did you actually try to run the code presented in this answer?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes and it gave me this error: Value of type 'PagesViewController' has no member 'presentPageVC', which I never got before

Comment: @Jones How is that error related to the answer or your question for that matter?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson a vc is generated based on the for loop hence if I remove the for loop then the VCs do not get generated you see, I have hardcoded the formatting in another view controller (where I created the init code) the for loop is in another controller

Comment: @Sh_Khan where would I put the "myControllers.append(vc)" part? would you write the line differently? I think I need this to make the VC display